# How to get the current sheet name into the cell in Numbers.app

Tags: numbers

Scenario:

- Have a spreadsheet (Numbers.app v3.6.2/El Capitan)
- it contains multiple `Sheets` (every sheet contains multiple tables, but this doesn't matter)
- Every sheet is renamed to some defined name, for example the `Sheet 2` is renamed to `Feb` (month name abbrev).
- need get into the cell content the *current sheet name* e.g. something like the hypothetical function `=GETSHEETNAME()`, so in the sheet named as `Feb`, want get to some cell the string `Feb`.

My reading of the `Numbers.app` function reference failed and I doesn't find any function for such operation. **Is it possible somehow?**

**EDIT**

At the https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/sheet.html I found some applescript, but haven't idea how to use it... :(

Comment: Note that depending on regional settings in your computer - separators may be twisted so instead of decimal being . it may be , and then you get function parameter separator to be ;
So technically there are many solutions, and either may or may not work.
Luckily - there are both separator options in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REGEX.EXTRACT(REFERENCE.NAME(;2);"[^:]+";;)` returns the sheet name of the current sheet

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! Your answer has been flagged as low-quality; it may work, but perhaps you can add references to the documentation?

Comment: Would be nice, unfortunately it says for me: "The formula contains a syntax error" and also I can't find any function called `REGEX`. Using `Numbers.app` ver 6.1.

Comment: Just found, the `REGEX` is probably introduced in the version 10.1, so unusable for me (I'm still using High Sierra (10.13.6)  and the 10.1 Numbers requires at least 10.15). Thanks anyway - couldn't accept it, but upvoting it as an possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that (I'm using Numbers version 10.3.5). If your version already supports the function `REFERENCE.NAME` you could use this variant: `LEFT(REFERENCE.NAME(;2;);FIND(":";REFERENCE.NAME(;2;))−1)`. Ugly, but works without `REGEX`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's changed for v13 (what I'm using) in macOS Monterey but to do this now I have to replace all zorro's uses of ";" with ",":

```
LEFT(REFERENCE.NAME(,2,),FIND(":",REFERENCE.NAME(,2,))−1)
```

If I don't then it fails with a syntax warning.

Thanks for the tip and for getting me 99.99% there, zorro!